# How to obtain trigger_id from Slack's Slash Commands?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I've successfully been able to create a basic slash command but the request body (sent from Slack triggered upon the slash command) does not include a `trigger_id`.  How do I obtain this `trigger_id`?  Apparently, I need this in order to generate a Slack dialog which is my ultimate goal.

The response looks something like this:

```
{ token: 'MY_TOKEN',
  team_id: 'MY_TEAM_ID',
  team_domain: 'testing',
  channel_id: 'D0JPDEPN5',
  channel_name: 'directmessage',
  user_id: 'U0JPD5E07',
  user_name: 'ryan',
  command: '/testcommand',
  text: '',
  response_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/commands/T0JP043M/3884242426501/bPgV4224Kflxhh6mmNF1O0YHp5' }
```

No `trigger_id` to be found.

Comment: In my interactions with slash commands I get the `trigger_id` properly. Have you [prepared your app for dialogs](https://api.slack.com/dialogs#preparing_apps_for_dialogs)? It could be the `trigger_id` is not provided until that's the case. Note you might need to reinstall your app, too.

Comment: Do you have your own Slack app and is it installed for your current Slack team?